# Procedure containing transaction leading to deadlock when executed in parallel in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Current scenario: we have a T-SQL procedure which fetches unprocessed data from `Table1` and dumps into `Table2` with certain manipulations on each record. The entire process is being executed in a transaction and a flag is maintained to signify if a record has been processed.

A SQL Server job has been created to execute this procedure at an interval of 2 min. (another job has been created to load Table1 with fresh data at an interval of 1 min)

In case when the first time job execution requires more than 2 min, the same job gets triggered again, this is leading to a dead lock.

The transaction within the T-SQL is for each record so shouldn't the table be released after processing each record so that even the same same job is triggered again it would be able to read the unprocessed rows.

Database isolation level maintained is "Read committed snapshot"

We were under the assumption that SQL Server would allow the process to run in parallel. What are we doing wrong here?

Note: we are a bunch of naive developers experimenting with SQL Server. Let us know if we are being dumb!

Here is the gist of what the `procedure` does

```
pr_process_data
begin
  select column1, column2, column3... from `table1`
  fetch into cursor
  open cursor

  while fetch status = 0
  begin loop
    begin transaction
    "queries to validate datatype, length of all the columns"
    if validation succeeds
      update `table1' valid flag = 'y'
    else
      update `table1` valid flag = 'n'
    commit
  end loop

  insert into `table2` select * from `table1' where valid = 'y'
end
```

The number of columns may vary anywhere between 20 to 40 and the number of validation can be anywhere between 3-5

Hope the example is clear enough!

Comment: For a scheduled job, SQL Server agent will check if a job is already running before starting it, if it is already running it will be skipped, so the job deadlocking with itself might not be your issue. It would help to see the SQL though, because if you are using explicit transactions you will be locking the entire table, not just the rows being modified. It also sounds like the manipulation is being done [RBAR](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/rbar--row-by-agonizing-row/), which may not be optimal, so again seeing the SQL would really assist in solving the problem.

Comment: Thanks for that GarethD. Learnt something new today. I have added the a sample code mimicking the actual procedure. This should provide more clarity of the issue.

Comment: Are you using explicit transactions? If so where are you beginning and committing each one? Is there a processed flag on table1, or do you delete processed rows?

Comment: Transaction gets opened withing my cursor for each row of `table1` (edited in my query). The processed flag exists in `table1` which gets updated row by row. Only the processed rows gets moved into `table2`. For now our requirement is to maintain all the rows in `table1`. This will be deleted on monthly basis in a clean up scripts.

Comment: My best guess would be the deadlock is between the processing and the import, so the table is locked while processing meaning the other job cannot load data to table 1. If possible, my suggestion would be to do the whole thing in SSIS, here you can read the data to import, do your validation etc, and then have a conditional split to move the data to either table 1 or table 2 depending on the validation. You can still set up your job to run this SSIS package, but because all the processing is outside of SQL you don't have to worry about concurrency.

Comment: Thanks Gareth. Somewhere we knew SSIS would be the best way to face the issue but wanted to see if setting appropriate Isolation level would solve the issue. But looks like SQL sever escalates the lock to table level though we are trying to apply it at row level. Correct me if i am wrong here.